# regex to match whatever between

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Please, I need some help to create the right regex.

I want to detect whatever between `Decode("` `")` to give me this output `2%65%66%_WHATEVER_8%74%74`

I tried a lot, but nothing works correctly to give me the exact output that I want.

My code:

```
$string = '
    <td class="red"><script type="text/javascript">Decode("2%65%66%_WHATEVER_8%74%74")</script></td>
    <td class="green"><script type="text/javascript">Decode("2%65%66%_WHATEVER_8%74%74")</script></td>
    <td class="red"><script type="text/javascript">Decode("2%65%66%_WHATEVER_8%74%74")</script></td>
';
$pattern = '/Decode("([^*]+)")/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you could use

```
Decode\("([^"]+)"\)
```

And take the first group, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/HZTfOl/1).

---

As `PHP` demo:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<script type="text/javascript">Decode("2%65%66%_WHATEVER_8%74%74")</script>
DATA;

$regex = '~Decode\("([^"]+)"\)~';

if (preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your input string, you only need the following pattern:

```
/\("\K[^"]+/
```

This brief pattern is appropriate/accurate because your targeted double-quoted substring is uniquely identified by the preceding `(`.

`preg_match_all()` will deliver the desired substrings in the fullstring match (`[0]`). This is faster and less bloating of the output array than using a capture group.

`\(` means "a literal opening parenthesis".  Without the backslash, regex will misinterpret your meaning and consider the `(` to mean: "start capturing from this point".

`\K` will restart the fullstring match.

`[^"]+` will greedily match one or more non-double-quote characters and stop just before it encounters a double quote.  This is a `negated character class`.  These are often used to improve efficiency while maintaining accuracy.

Code:  (Demo: https://3v4l.org/UmaaC )

```
$string = '
<td class="red"><script type="text/javascript">Decode("2%65%66%_WHATEVER_8%74%74")</script></td>
<td class="green"><script type="text/javascript">Decode("2%65%66%_WHATEVER_8%74%74")</script></td>
<td class="red"><script type="text/javascript">Decode("2%65%66%_WHATEVER_8%74%74")</script></td>';
$pattern = '/\("\K[^"]+/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2%65%66%_WHATEVER_8%74%74
    [1] => 2%65%66%_WHATEVER_8%74%74
    [2] => 2%65%66%_WHATEVER_8%74%74
)
```